# Create an offline installer of npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

**Problem:**

I have a very flaky internet connection at my place.
Due to this when I try to do

```
npm install -g glup
```

it stops the download before completion.
I have tried downloading several times but all in vain.

**Thinking about my options**

I have a friend in other city with high speed internet, I can ask him to somehow package the `glup` and provided it to me using dropbox, then i can use any download manager to download it partially with my flaky connection.

But the sad thing is he doesn't know how to do it. (help on this front is also appreciated)

Can anyone help me out with this situation?

P.S: I am doing a course from Udacity and due to my flaky internet connection I am kind of facing lot of issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), `npm install` supports installing from a tarball file sitting on your filesystem. So, as long as your friend can create and supply you a tarball of the npm package you are looking for - you should be good to go.

Below is a quote from the docs.

[image: npm install docs]

**UPDATE**: To create a tarball file from an npm package, you can just run `npm pack package_name`. For example,

```
npm pack underscore
```

will create a `.tgz` file for the latest version of `underscore.js` npm package. See the documentation for `npm pack` [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack).

Comment: how will he create tarball of npm package?

Answer (score 0):

Not answering directly your question, but I was just struggling with network connection behind a corporate firewall with npm for hours. Then I tried yarn, the package manager from Facebook. Wow, it worked like a charm, install of the package I needed plus deps. done within a minute.